# ModX Revo wont save TVs with URLs

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have set up a site using Revo and have made some URL TVs. However, when I put a URL into these TVs when editing a Resource the Resource wont save - ModX just infinitely loops the saving progress bar. The same occurs whether I use http or https.

The only way I can circumvent it is if I put the http in my template code such as:

```
http://[[*urltv]]
```

but this is bad practice as links could be either http or https.

I've tried both Text and URL TV types too.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

EDIT:

Video of issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqlZbckGEiA&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Comment: any errors in apache logs?

Comment: @IanBrindley yep 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue recently.

Using the 'Web Developer->Network->403->Response' on Firefox, figured Cloudflare was blocking the Ajax request.
Had to temporarily inactivate the Cloudflare WAF to save Resources on ModX.

Tried playing around with the Cloudflare WAF settings, but nothing seems to turn the block off without having to switch off the entire WAF temporarily.

Hope this helps someone.